# Using different e-mail account to send mail

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I want to use a Excel macro to send a mail to a company. This mail should consist of a piece of text, a table and then the rest of the text.

In the function below I've compiled some code that works the way I want, but I would like to send the e-mail not from my personal account but from a corporate business account (in the code I refer to the latter as myemailadres@outlook.com). I think I have to use the .SendUsingAccount function, but if I implement it like shown below, the e-mail is send using my personal email account and not the one I specify. Can somebody help?

```
Sub Test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim TargetSheet As String
Dim i As Long
Dim StrBodybegin As String
Dim StrBodyend As String
Dim Startcell
Dim TargetRow As Integer

   TargetSheet = Range("L24").value 'L24 refers to a name of a company, there is also a sheet in the workbook with the exact same name. 

    With Application.WorksheetFunction 'this I copied from the code from Ron de Bruijn
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        TargetRow = .Match("TOTAAL", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetSheet).Range("W1:W60"), 0) 'setting range of table I want to copy
        Set Startcell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetSheet).Range("W15")
        Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetSheet).Range(Startcell, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetSheet).Cells(TargetRow + 1, 38))

        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            .ScreenUpdating = False
        End With

        StrBodybegin = "Text 1"

        StrBodyend = "Text 2" 

        On Error Resume Next

        With OutMail
            .To = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Voorblad").Range("L23").value 'L23 refers to email adress
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Subject" 
            .HTMLBody = StrBodybegin & RangetoHTML(rng) & StrBodyend 'using the Ron de Bruin function RangetoHTML to copy in the table defined by the rng
            .SendUsingAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts("myemailadres@outlook.com") 'the line that does not work :(
            .Send
        End With

        On Error GoTo 0

        With Application
            .EnableEvents = True
            .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With

        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You can send such a mail using Outlook, only if the account you want using is also added to Outlook. Otherwise, you can try sending mails from a different account using CDO...

Comment: @FaneDuru the other account is also an Outlook account for which I have the permission to send e-mails. I would be really helped if the solution can be done with the .SendUsingAccount function

Comment: Then, try my answer piece of code, please.

Comment: @FaneDuru it did not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the property `.SentOnBehalfOfName = "user@domain"` if you have access to that mailbox or user or whatever. Even if it's not added to your outlook, like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim TargetSheet As String
Dim i As Long
Dim StrBodybegin As String
Dim StrBodyend As String
Dim Startcell
Dim TargetRow As Integer

   TargetSheet = Range("L24").Value 'L24 refers to a name of a company, there is also a sheet in the workbook with the exact same name.

    With Application.WorksheetFunction 'this I copied from the code from Ron de Bruijn
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        TargetRow = .Match("TOTAAL", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetSheet).Range("W1:W60"), 0) 'setting range of table I want to copy
        Set Startcell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetSheet).Range("W15")
        Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetSheet).Range(Startcell, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetSheet).Cells(TargetRow + 1, 38))

        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            .ScreenUpdating = False
        End With

        StrBodybegin = "Text 1"

        StrBodyend = "Text 2"

        On Error Resume Next

        With OutMail
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "user@domain"
            .To = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Voorblad").Range("L23").Value 'L23 refers to email adress
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Subject"
            .HTMLBody = StrBodybegin & RangetoHTML(rng) & StrBodyend 'using the Ron de Bruin function RangetoHTML to copy in the table defined by the rng
            .SendUsingAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts("myemailadres@outlook.com") 'the line that does not work :(
            .Send
        End With

        On Error GoTo 0

        With Application
            .EnableEvents = True
            .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With

        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: With .SentOnBehalfOfName = "user@domain" you mean .SentOnBehalfOfName = "myemailadres@outlook.com" ?

Comment: Yes @Sander_H just that

Answer (score 0):

Find your account loop through `accounts`.

```vb
Dim outApp As object, outNS as object
Dim accounts As object, account As object, myAccount As object

set outApp =createobject("outlook.application")
set outNS = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set accounts = outNS.Accounts
For Each account in accounts
    if account.SmtpAddress = "myemailadrs@outlook.com" then
        set myAccount = account
        Exit For
    end if
Next account

With outApp.CreateItem(0)
    .to = "someone@abc.com"
    '...
    Set .SendUsingAccount = myAccount
    '....
End With
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work, the e-mail is still send from my personal account

Comment: What if rewrite `.SendUsingAccount = myAccount` with `Set .SendUsingAccount = myAccount`?

Answer (score 0):

Try, please:

```
.SendUsingAccount  = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").accounts.Item("myemailadres@outlook.com")
```

And, when you try debugging, it is recommended to comment the line `On Error Resume Next`.  You can not see where and what error appears. In fact, it should not exist at all, if everything is correct..

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. The email was stil send from my personal account